# Prove $1-\frac{\sin x}{x} \geq \gamma \frac{x^{2}}{1+x^{2}} \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: calculus, analysis

Prove there exists a constant $\gamma>0$ such that
$$
1-\frac{\sin x}{x} \geq \gamma \frac{x^{2}}{1+x^{2}} \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}.
$$

---

Since the functions of both sides are even, it suffices to consider $[0,\,+\infty)$ only.

I think a straight way is to prove the minimum of
$$
\frac{1+x^2}{x^2}-\frac{1+x^2}{x^2}\cdot\frac{\sin x}{x}
$$
is greater than $0$.
But this needs too much effort to calculate.
So I'm appreciate if there is a more elegant approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\frac {1+x^{2}} {x^{2}}(1-\frac  {\sin x} x)$ for $0 <x<\infty$. Then $f$ is a continuous function on $(0,\infty)$ and $f(x) \to 1$ as $ x \to \infty$.  Use L'Hopital's Rule to show that $f(x) \to \frac 1 6$ as $ x \to 0$. Also, $f(x) >0$ for all $x$. Can you show that any positive continuous function on $(0,\infty)$ with positive limits at $0$ and $\infty$ has  a positive lower bound $\gamma$?